# How to LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2 WHERE table2 row fulfills certain conditions

Tags: mysql, join

Please consider this query:

```
SELECT table1.* ,
    (SELECT quantity FROM table2 WHERE id = table1.id AND table2.location = 10) quantity, 
    (SELECT reorder_level FROM table2 WHERE id = table1.id AND table2.location = 10) reorder_level, 
    (SELECT stock_date FROM table2 WHERE id = table1.id AND table2.location = 10) stock_date
FROM table1
WHERE category_id = 5 ORDER BY table1.id;
```

The aliases `quantity`, `location` and `stock_date` are obviously referencing a a row in `table2` that fulfill the condition: `id=table1.id` and `location=10`.

This query works, but is probably suboptimal as a result of the clumsy subqueries.

How can I best join `table1` to `table2` USING(id) but only on rows where `location` is also 10.

TIP: One row from `table1` has many rows in `table2`.

Unfortunately, the actual table definitions are much more complex, and I reckoned it might be counter-productive to dump the entire thing on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional condition in `ON()` part so it will join only rows which fulfills the provided criteria

```
SELECT t1.* ,
t2.quantity ,
t2.reorder_level,
t2.stock_date
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.location = 10
WHERE t1.category_id = 5 
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Another way would be use a subselect for your table2 and select only rows where location is equal to 10

```
SELECT t1.* ,
t2.quantity ,
t2.reorder_level,
t2.stock_date
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE t2.location = 10)  t2
 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.category_id = 5 
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Comment: First way worked, (and I'm sure 2nd way would work too). Interesting that I DID try the first way. I think the bug that affected my application arose from my starting with `SELECT *` rather than `SELECT t1.*`. Otherwise, I found that it did fetch from the required row of `t2`. Thank you very much.